# error on declaring and using function on xsl

Tags: templates, function, xslt, xslt-2.0

just trying to create and use an XSL function which display the content of the node if any or a dash if empty.

Here is some parts of the file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:qes="http://www.qwamci.com">

  <xsl:function name="qes:textOrDash" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="mynode" />
    <xsl:sequence select="if (fn:compare(translate($mynode, ' ', ''), '')=0) then '-' else $mynode" />
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="Response">
    <xsl:value-of select="qes:textOrDash(./SOME/OTHER/XPATH/TO/NODE)" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error :

```
Erreur:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.textOrDash([ExpressionContext,] ).
```

Some idea?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the most likely cause of the problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems that you are trying to execute an XSLT 2.0 transformation using an XSLT 1.0 processor**.

In XSLT 1.0 there is no `<xsl:function>` instruction, but one may use templates:

```
<xsl:call-template name="textOrDash">
 <xsl:with-param name="mynode" select="SomeXPath-Expression"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template name="textOrDash">
 <xsl:param name="mynode" select="someDefault"/>

<!-- Processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you right! i am using AXIS 1!
Any solution for creating function in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @Patrick-Ferreira: In XSLT1.0 just use `<xsl:call-template>` for any named template.

Comment: @Patrick-Ferreira: I have updated my answer to show how to write and call named templates in XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some parameters for your function. You have defined a function `qes:textOrDash()` you need to add `<xsl:param name="input"/>` to your function definition and then reference `$input` instead of `.` so you have:

```
<xsl:function name="qes:textOrDash" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="input" />
  <xsl:sequence select="if (fn:compare(translate($input, ' ', ''), '')=0) then '-' else ." />
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. The signature of the function as referenced didn't match the signature of the function as defined.

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply. I already tryed that, but i had the same issue :(

Comment: There are no context node in function body, so `.` abbreviation of `self::node()` rise an error.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you need a function for that. As example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:value-of select="(.,'-')[normalize-space(.)][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<test>string</test>
```

Output:

```
string
```

With this input:

```
<test></test>
```

Output:

```
-
```

With this input:

```
<test><not-string-value/></test>
```

Output:

```
-
```

And this input:

```
<test>&#x20;&#xA;&#x9;&#xD;</test>
```

Output

```
-
```

About your function: you are only striping space character...

Comment: Shorter: `(.[normalize-space()],'-')[1]`